# Android Studio Gradle Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' using Ion koush lib

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, androidasync-koush, ion-koush

I want to use the Ion Lib from koush in Android Studio. But after I synchronize the libraries in my gradle file and try to run the application a strange error occurs.

My thought is that the Ion Lib does not accept the other libraries in my gradle file.

```
Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComKoushikduttaAsyncAndroidasync218Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComKoushikduttaIonIon218Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComRengwuxianMaterialedittextLibrary214Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComSpecyciResidemenu16Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
:app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
6 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

My Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sample.test.soft"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.specyci:residemenu:1.6+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.1.8'
}
```

In my gradle file I replaced the '+' of ion and androidasync with the version numbers.

Comment: Complie the code with compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Compile the build with**

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

In Your **AndroidManifest.xml** add this lines **android:name**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >
```

And In your **build.gradle** also add

```
dexOptions {
    //incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Welcome @ninjaxelite  :) :)

Answer (score 1):

> From the log you have posted j**ava.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead
>   limit exceeded**. It's seems your Android Studio ran out of memory.

To raise the heap limit of the dexing operation add this to your `android` closure:

```
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

This will solve all the GC overhead issues, and you can have substantially more dependencies. and I have noted that you are compiling the entire services `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2` from google play.

> Selectively compiling APIs into your executable

*In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile
 the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made
 it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including
 framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536
 limit.
 From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service   APIs into your app.*

Read [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) for further.

Answer (score 0):

First clean project.
For me it worked when I removed the classpath of google play from dependencies
and now it looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```