# Multiple dex file error while adding Firebase analytics in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-analytics

I get the following error when I add Firebase analytics in my Android Studio project:
"Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementContentProvider;"

Id really be thankful if someone tells me where the additional AppmeasurementContentProvider is coming from and the corresponding "exclude" command.

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    exclude 'com.google.android.gms.measurement'

}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.elisiumlabs.sarthi"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
    testInstrumentationRunner    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

}

dependencies {

compile project(':androidQuery')
compile project(':pinnedSectionListActivity')
compile project(':volley')
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0"
// compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'


compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms.measurement'
}
compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2')
        {
           exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms.measurement'
        }
/*compile files('libs/appcompat_v7.jar')*/
compile files('libs/commons-io-1.4.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
/*compile files('libs/objectify-5.0.3.jar')*/
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.1.jar')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
// Optional -- Hamcrest library
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
// Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
/*  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-    core:2.2.1') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}*/
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   contrib:2.2.2') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'){
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
// Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'){
      // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test runner
      // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  }


}
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Your App for Multidex with Gradle 
reference https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Modify the module-level build.gradle file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output, as shown in the following code snippet:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

extends the Application class, you can override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex. For more information, see the MultiDexApplication reference documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to my answer....

**here is the link**

[Android Studio Gradle Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' using Ion koush lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009839/android-studio-gradle-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-using-ion/38010173#38010173)

Please take the Google service as my answer and also add to your gradle some code as shown also add some code in your mainfiest file

And also true the multidexenable with comile the multidex as shown in answer

**First Compile the build with**

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

In Your **AndroidManifest.xml** add this lines **android:name**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >
```

And In your **build.gradle** also add

```
dexOptions {
    //incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you could mix GCM and FCM, because FCM is the new GCM. Logically, they must share a near similar api to interwork.

You should choose either FCM or GCM. From your build.gradles looks like you work with gcm. So remove the FCM code. Remove these lines:

```
compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2')
{
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms.measurement'
}
```

Read the play service setup with GCM at [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)
and FCM at [Add Firebase to your Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Answer (score 0):

When I try and the version levels do not match, Android Studio gives the following warning:

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)

Thus setting to the same version levels resolves the dependencies not working with each other

```
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0')
    compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0')
```